# Why do I have to reference my models in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I don't know if this is an EF Core question or Asp.Net Core 2 question.  I'm just wondering why I have to reference my Models directory in a view for this example (HelloNurse).

I'm using .Net Core 2.2.  I'm also using the Fluent API in separate configuration files.  Finally, I'm using two `DbContexts`.  One for Identity and `EfficacyDbContext` for my data.  Oh.  I'm also using Areas.

DbContext

```
namespace Efficacy.Data
{
    public class EfficacyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; protected set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ContactType> ContactType { get; protected set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HelloNurse> HelloNurse { get; protected set; }

        public EfficacyDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactEntityTypeConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
namespace Efficacy.Models.Entities
{
    public class HelloNurse
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Hello { get; set; }
        public string Nurse { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace Efficacy.Areas.Ops.Controllers
{
    public class HelloNurseController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EfficacyDBContext _db;

        public HelloNurseController(EfficacyDBContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _db.HelloNurse.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@using Efficacy.Models.Entities @* <-Why do I have to include this reference?*@
@model IEnumerable<HelloNurse>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Index</h1>
```

I just think it's a little verbose to reference my Models directory when I'm already passing the `DbContext` to the view.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Because your view `@model` is using `HelloNurse` *class* which is coming from `Efficacy.Models.Entities` *namespace*

Comment: Although the MS scaffolding seems to encourage the practice, many developers prefer to keep the EF entity models out of the presentation tier, and instead, project tailored ViewModels specific for each View (or Ajax call). In this case, the ViewModels are then shared between Controller and View.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
@using Efficacy.Models.Entities

@model IEnumerable<HelloNurse>
```

Just add the fully qualified namespace right in the type declaration:

```
@model IEnumerable<Efficacy.Models.Entities.HelloNurse>
```

The view needs to know the model's "Type", and for that to happen we need to give it a fully qualified namespace.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: I should have been more explicit. The view needs to know the model's "Type", and for that to happen we need to give it a fully qualified namespace.